# Is there an efficient way to join many (1000+) DF?

Tags: pyspark

I'm fairly new to Spark and I have a DF that stacks 8000 time series on top of each other. These time series make more sense as individual columns so I decided to filter them one by one and **join them on the timestamp** in a new master DF.

So far so good, however as soon as I try that I get a **OOM error**.

```
# My stacked DF and the name of the columns
stocks_df.cache()
tickers = ["TS1", "TS2", "TS3", ...]

def filter_for_symbol(ticker):
    security = stocks_df.filter(stocks_df["Symbol"] == ticker).drop("Symbol")
    # Avoids conflict in column names...
    # for f in features:
    #     security = security.withColumnRenamed(f, ticker + "_" + f)
    return security

# Aggregation Loop
acc_df = filter_for_symbol(tickers[0])
for ticker in tickers[1:]:
    security = filter_for_symbol(ticker)
    acc_df = acc_df.join(security, on="Date", how="outer")
```

What would be a better way of doing what I'm doing in terms of speed and/or memory management?

---

**UPDATE**

What I have, stocks_df: dim = (8000 time series * 3125 entries) x 9 features

```
+-------------+--------+------+-----+------+
|    Date     | Symbol | Open | ... | Close|
+-------------+--------+------+-----+------+
| 2020/01/01  |  TS1   | 10.0 | ... | 12.2 |
| 2020/01/02  |  TS1   | 12.2 | ... | 13.2 |
|    ...      |  ...   | ...  | ... | ...  |
+-------------+--------+------+-----+------+
| 2020/01/01  |  TS2   | 29.9 | ... | 32.2 |
| 2020/01/02  |  TS2   | 32.2 | ... | 19.2 |
|    ...      |  ...   | ...  | ... | ...  |
+-------------+--------+------+-----+------+
|    ...      |  ...   | ...  | ... | ...  |
+-------------+--------+------+-----+------+
```

---

What I would like to get: dim = 3125 x (8000 * 9)

```
+-------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|    Date     | TS1_Open :  ...  : TS1_Close | TS2_Close |  TS2_..|
+-------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 2020/01/01  |   10.0   :  ...  :    12.2   |    12.2   :  ...   |
| 2020/01/02  |   12.2   :  ...  :    13.2   |    13.2   :  ...   |
|    ...      |   ...    :  ...  :    ...    |    ...    :  ...   |
+-------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

---

What I get instead:
java.lang.OOM

Comment: hold on, are you ending up with the same df just reshaped? can you share `stocks_df.index` and `stocks_df.columns` ? it can probably be fixed with `stocks_df.groupby('Symbol')`

Comment: You didn't include `stocks_df.index` ... is `Date` and index or a column? Take a look at [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects)

Comment: IMHO it would be much more efficient to run a (very verbose) pivot then an aggregation on a single dataset, than run 1000 joins on 1001 shards of that same dataset. And that's not specific to Spark; this kind of issues has been around for decades with relational databases. E.g. `select case when SYMBOL = 'TS1' then OPEN else null end as TS1_OPEN, case...` then a `select max(TS1_OPEN) as TS1_OPEN, ...` to flatten out all the Nulls.

Comment: use `Dask` for this

Comment: @RichieV I'm actually working on a Spark DF that's why I didn't provide an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just `pivot` your dataframe?

```
df.show(10, False)

+----------+-----+----+-----+
|Date      |ymbol|Open|Close|
+----------+-----+----+-----+
|2020/01/01|TS1  |10.0|12.2 |
|2020/01/02|TS1  |12.2|13.2 |
|2020/01/01|TS2  |29.9|32.2 |
|2020/01/02|TS2  |32.2|19.2 |
+----------+-----+----+-----+

cols = df.columns[2:]
tickers = ['TS1', 'TS2']

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy('Date') \
  .pivot('ymbol', tickers) \
  .agg(*map(lambda x: f.sum(f.col(x)).alias(x), cols)) \
  .show(10, False)

+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|Date      |TS1_Open|TS1_Close|TS2_Open|TS2_Close|
+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|2020/01/01|10.0    |12.2     |29.9    |32.2     |
|2020/01/02|12.2    |13.2     |32.2    |19.2     |
+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: That's actually the smart of doing it compared to my aggregation loop. I tried it out but I get a `java.lang.OOMError` when I call `df.groupBy("Date")`. I also tried tweaking the SparkSession with `.config("spark.driver.memory", "10g")` to no avail. I don't think that did any good because I still have a lot of spare RAM...

Comment: I have 24 million rows (2.5GB on disk). For now I'm just running it on my computer that has 16GB RAM. I was hoping to do some more work on it before running it on a cluster

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicate rows in `Date + Symbol', you can set them to be the index, then move` Symbol`to columns. You will get a MultiIndex as columns, containing`[('TS1, 'Open'), ('TS1', 'High'), ..., ('TSn', 'Close')]`

```
df = (
    df.set_index(['Date', 'Symbol'])
    .unstack() # moves the inner-most level by default
)
```

**WARNING**

Ifa symbol is not present in some date, `unstack` will fill that spot in with `np.nan`. If this happens often you will use more memory than the data really needs. Should be fine in your case but look out when you increase your data size.

Comment: That's a very clean solution and works well with a smaller sample. I converted my spark_df back to a p_df and tried it out. However the operation takes more than 15GB of RAM at which point my kernel crashes :/ Any thoughts?